# Dotnet 6 HttpLogging - filter out some controllers

Tags: logging, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I am using AddHttpLogging middleware for my Dotnet 6 web api project. For diagnostic purposes I have such configuration:

```
                var loggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestPropertiesAndHeaders |
                                    HttpLoggingFields.ResponsePropertiesAndHeaders |
                                    HttpLoggingFields.ResponseStatusCode |
                                    HttpLoggingFields.RequestQuery |
                                    HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody;
```

Due to sensitive information, I want to prevent logging request body of some controllers. How can I them filter out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, use 'ExcludeFilter' method to prevent logging request body of some controllers, it is provided by the AddHttpLogging middleware.
Like this;

```
app.UseAddHttpLogging(options => {
options.ExcludeFilter = context =>
    context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName == "YourController";
});
```

Or another way is;

```
app.UseAddHttpLogging(options => {
options.ExcludeFilter = excludeFilterOptions => {
    excludeFilterOptions.ControllerTypeNames.Add("YourController");
};
});
```

**(Edited)**
**Update:** For some reason above solution didn't work. So I found another solution that worked. Here's a demo I coded for you; https://github.com/usama-mirza/HttpLoggingWithFilter

Try the following instead of app.UseHttpLogging();

```
app.UseWhen(
context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Sensitive"), //SensitiveController.cs
builder => builder.UseHttpLogging());
```

Comment: It says "'HttpLoggingOptions' does not contain a definition for 'ExcludeFilter' and no accessible extension method 'ExcludeFilter' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpLoggingOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Okay so I looked into it then found a solution. I'll edit the answer to post it. And turns out 'UseAddHttpLogging' requires a nuget package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides'. But idk it's not working either with .net 6.