# ASP.NET Core 8 - exclude HTTP request body from logging for certain paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, httprequest, .net-8.0

Similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74808487/1537195): I'm using `HttpRequestLogging` like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(loggingOptions =>
{
    loggingOptions.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.Request | HttpLoggingFields.Response;
}
```

However, for certain request paths, I would like to change the logging fields to not include logging the body, basically switch to

```
LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestProperties | HttpLoggingFields.ResponsePropertiesAndHeaders;
```

if the request path contains `/myspecial/request/notToLog`

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, check the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging - The logging can either be configured per-endpoint or at run-time using `IHttpLoggingInterceptor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways which can help you to achieve that (based on actual case/setup):

1. Use [endpoint-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#endpoint-specific-configuration) via attributes (if you want to customize specific endpoints), works both for controllers and minimal APIs endpoints:

   ```cs
   app.MapGet("/log-only-duration", [HttpLogging(HttpLoggingFields.Duration)]() => "will not be logged");
   ```

   ```cs
   [ApiController]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
   {
        [HttpGet()]
        [HttpLogging(loggingFields: HttpLoggingFields.Duration)]
        public string Get() => "will not be logged";
   }
   ```
2. Use [`IHttpLoggingInterceptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttplogginginterceptor):

   ```cs
   builder.Services.AddHttpLoggingInterceptor<CustomHttpLoggingInterceptor>();

   class CustomHttpLoggingInterceptor : IHttpLoggingInterceptor
   {
       public ValueTask OnRequestAsync(HttpLoggingInterceptorContext logContext)
       {
           // some predicate when to disable
           if (logContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("toDisable", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
           {
               logContext.TryDisable(HttpLoggingFields.Request | HttpLoggingFields.Response);
           }

           return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
       }

       public ValueTask OnResponseAsync(HttpLoggingInterceptorContext logContext) => ValueTask.CompletedTask;
   }
   ```
3. In some cases it can be appropriate to conditionally enable the logging with [middleware branching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline) (effectively disabling it for the rest):

   ```cs
   // some predicate when to enable logging
   app.UseWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.Value.Contains("toDisable", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
      aB => aB.UseHttpLogging());
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot! the second option did it for me